# Can we have an infinite sequence of paradoxical partitioning below power set?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Can we have the following in absence of choice?

$\exists f [f= \{P_i: i \in \omega\} \land \forall i \in \omega ( P_{i+1}|P_i  \land |P_{i+1}| > |P_i| \land |P_i| < |\mathcal P(P_0)|)]$

where $``|"$ denotes "is a partition of".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can have an arbitrarily long sequence of paradoxical partitions. Pick your favorite ordinal $\alpha>1$, in your case $\omega$.

Start with a model of $\sf CH$, for simplicity purposes, then add $\omega_\alpha\times\omega$ Cohen reals, and permute each $\omega$ block so that it is Dedekind-finite, but do not permute the sequence of blocks. This gives you a surjection from the reals onto $\omega_\alpha$, but no injection from $\omega_2$ into the reals.

Now partition the reals into $2^{\aleph_0}+\aleph_2$ parts, and then partition that one (by partitioning the part of size continuum) into $2^{\aleph_0}+\aleph_3$ parts, and so on. Since all of these partitions are derived from a fixed surjection from the reals onto $\omega_\alpha$, the sequence of these partitions is also in the model.

Comment: Do you know whether this can consistently ever fail if there are paradoxical partitions at all?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The question asks if we can have countable sequences of paradoxical partitions. What am I asking is whether such sequences must exist as soon as there are paradoxical partitions at all.

Comment: Ohh, I see. That's a nice question. I'm not sure. It seems plausible, since AC follows from "there is a bound on cardinals between X and P(X)" (if my memory serves me well), and paradoxical partitions sit in that gap. But that's of course more complicated than just this. We utilise for this construction, here, a gap between the Lindenbaum and Hartogs of a set, but it is also possible that those are always the same, in which case you need to find a different strategy.